# select distinct over each column in a table returning multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get a more simple query that runs through all columns of a table and returns the same number of tables for each column.

For example...

```
select distinct a from tbl;
select distinct b from tbl;
select distinct c from tbl;
select distinct d from tbl;
```

gives the results I would like but I would have to type out each column. How can I write a query that would go through all the columns and give me the same results without having to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to generate and execute Dynamic SQL.

Query the sys tables/views to get all the columns in `tbl` and build a SQL String that issues a SELECT command for each column returned.

Then execute the SQL String.

Comment: how would I start on making that string? i have the query for all the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
  STUFF((
    SELECT ' GO ' + CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT ',col.name,' FROM tbl') from sys.columns col
left join sys.tables tab on tab.object_id=col.object_id
where tab.name='tbl'
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,2,2,'') AS Names
FROM tbl t1
```

It will generate the query dynamically.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I get one column of null values